# Could anyone explain What is trim argument in mean

Tags: r, mean, trim

```
x <- c(0:2, 50)
mean(x,0.9)
#[1] 1.5
mean(x)
#[1] 13.25
mean(x,0.10)
#[1] 13.25
mean(x,0.50)
#[1] 1.5
mean(x,0.4)
#[1] 1.5
mean(x,0.3)
#[1] 1.5
mean(x,0.2)
#[1] 13.25
```

Could anyone explain in detail how `trim` argument work in R functions

Comment: Did you read `?mean`?

Comment: of course I red the mean function ... but I am not understanding ....
also red the thread https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-September/079213.html

Comment: I also found documentation confusing, because now after reading the answer below, my reaction is "why would this property be useful and how come I've not had an analagous property in other scripting languages like python/php etc..."

Comment: @nicola `?mean` only lists `trim` as a valid parameter there is no explanation of what it is or how it should be interpreted.

Comment: @user3338098 I read this from `?mean`: `trim: the fraction (0 to 0.5) of observations to be trimmed from
          each end of ‘x’ before the mean is computed.  Values of trim
          outside that range are taken as the nearest endpoint.` And in the `Value` section there is a detailed explanation of what it means.

Comment: @nicola still to this day: `?mean` results in `Arithmetic Mean     Description: Generic function for the (trimmed) arithmetic mean.  Usage: mean(x, ...); ## Default S3 method: mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...); Arguments: x: [ proper description of x ] [a few blank lines] ...: further arguments passed to or from other methods. Value: [followed by 3 blank lines] References: [a single reference] See Also: [ 2 blank lines] Examples: x <- c(0:10, 50); xm <- mean(x); c(xm, mean(x, trim = 0.10))` that is it the end and nothing else.  You may have documentation, but mine is sparse and incomplete.

Answer (score 9):

'trim' specifies the fraction of removed elements from two sides of data ... 
after removing these elements, the mean is calculated ...
here the number of elements is 4
and if we remove 0.1 fraction of 4 it means we are removing 0.1*4 of array ....
this number is lower than 1 so we do not remove any item...
when we assign 'trim' to 0.5, it means we are removing 0.5*4 of data
after that the function will compute the average of remaining elements

Answer (score 0):

*"Values of trim outside that range are taken as the nearest endpoint."*

I think it might be performing winsorization to the values which fall outside the trim boundary. Then using those winsored values plus the regular values which were inside the trim boundry.